# Font family has no effect in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, expression-blend, win-universal-app

This is definitely not the case in WP8.

However in the new Blend come with VS2013, the font family doesn't have any effect either in Blend Designer or runtime.

```
<TextBlock Text="test" 
           FontSize="{StaticResource HubHeaderFontSize}" 
           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
<TextBlock Text="test" 
           FontSize="{StaticResource HubHeaderFontSize}" 
           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
```

Are they still Segoe WP or Segoe UI?

What I have noticed is, if I change the font weight, it shows the correct font. But I really want to be able to use the built-in font family resources. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From generic.xaml:

```
<!-- Global font family -->
<FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyNormal">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyLight">Segoe WP Light</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilySemiLight">Segoe WP SemiLight</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilySemiBold">Segoe WP Semibold</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
```

It appears that those fonts aren't embedded...

Comment: Sorry, what generic.xaml? Did you create it?

Comment: No, it's the file where the ThemeResources are defined (for example, press F12 when the cursor is on PhoneFontFamilySemiBold to see its definition)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that!